# Hiding the default scrollbar on an HTML page without using overflow:hidden?

Tags: javascript, css

Without using:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```

How can I hide the scroll bar?

Note - I need overflow for other elements.

[image]

Comment: so turn on overflow for the other elements? `div{overflow:auto}`-type thing.

Comment: I don't quite understand your reasoning for not using `overflow:hidden` on body. Other elements can still have the property overflow: auto even when the body does not.

Comment: @timo Please wait a sec. screenshot coming.

Comment: Perhaps a fiddle would be of more use.

Comment: @timo Let me know if it makes sense

Comment: Basically you want to have overflow, but you want only to hide the scrollbar?

Comment: I want overflow x but I don't want overflow y on the same container. But you cannot have no overflow and overflow on the same time. It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

This works for webkit:

```
#element::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

If you want all scrollbars hidden, use:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

For Chrome and Safari browsers, use:

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
```

There is also a CSS rule that can hide scrollbars in IE 10+.

```
.element { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
```

But the `overflow:hidden` is still most popular.

Comment: Thanks but Webkit is not compatible for all browsers. FF, Edge won't work with this.

Comment: There used to be a CSS rule that could hide scrollbars in Firefox, but it has since been deprecated.  The rule was: 
`.element { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp